# How to get the Sudoku 2D-array index, given its "sub-grid" and "cell-in-the-sub-grid" indexes?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, sudoku

I'm working on a sudoku thing, and I'm having trouble reducing one part of it.

I'm designing a `SudokuBoard` object to have an underlying 2D byte array, and three different views of that array: row-units, column-units and grid units. A grid is the nine-by-nine blocks, indexed like this:

```
        GRID INDEX

        |         |
   0    |    1    |    2
        |         |
 -------------------------
        |         |
   3    |    4    |    5
        |         |
 -------------------------
        |         |
   6    |    7    |    8
        |         |
```

Where each grid has nine cells, indexed like this

```
CELL INDEX

   0 1 2
   3 4 5
   6 7 8
```

Here is the 2d array coordinates for the board:

```
                    2D-ARRAY COORDINATE

[0,0] [0,1] [0,2]  |  [0,3] [0,4] [0,5]  |  [0,6] [0,7] [0,8]
[1,0] [1,1] [1,2]  |  [1,3] [1,4] [1,5]  |  [1,6] [1,7] [1,8]
[2,0] [2,1] [2,2]  |  [2,3] [2,4] [2,5]  |  [2,6] [2,7] [2,8]
-------------------+---------------------+-------------------
[3,0] [3,1] [3,2]  |  [3,3] [3,4] [3,5]  |  [3,6] [3,7] [3,8]
[4,0] [4,1] [4,2]  |  [4,3] [4,4] [4,5]  |  [4,6] [4,7] [4,8]
[5,0] [5,1] [5,2]  |  [5,3] [5,4] [5,5]  |  [5,6] [5,7] [5,8]
-------------------+---------------------+-------------------
[6,0] [6,1] [6,2]  |  [6,3] [6,4] [6,5]  |  [6,6] [6,7] [6,8]
[7,0] [7,1] [7,2]  |  [7,3] [7,4] [7,5]  |  [7,6] [7,7] [7,8]
[8,0] [8,1] [8,2]  |  [8,3] [8,4] [8,5]  |  [8,6] [8,7] [8,8]
```

I've created a function to get the array-coordinate, given the grid and cell indexes. Determining the column index was a brain-buster, but I figured it out to be

```
int colIdx = (cell_idx % 3) + ((grid_idx % 3) * 3);
```

I also figured out do determine the row index, but I am unhappy with how complicated this is.

```
int rowIdx = -1;
if(grid_idx < 3)  {
   rowIdx = ((cell_idx < 3) ? 0
      :  ((cell_idx < 6) ? 1 : 2));
}  else if(grid_idx < 6)  {
   rowIdx = ((cell_idx < 3) ? 3
      :  ((cell_idx < 6) ? 4 : 5));
}  else  {
   rowIdx = ((cell_idx < 3) ? 6
      :  ((cell_idx < 6) ? 7 : 8));
}
```

If anyone has ideas on how to reduce this, ideally to a mathmatical formula, I'd appreciate it.

Here's a working application that demonstrates it. Thanks for any help.

```
  import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>{@code SudokuGridUnitCoordinates}</P>
 **/
public class SudokuGridUnitCoordinates  {
   public static final void main(String[] idxZeroGridIdx_0to8)  {
     int gridIdx = -1;
     try  {
        gridIdx = Integer.parseInt(idxZeroGridIdx_0to8[0]);
        if(gridIdx < 0  ||  gridIdx > 8)  {
           throw  new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
     }  catch(IllegalArgumentException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  x)  {
        throw  new IllegalArgumentException("The first element in idxZeroGridIdx_0to8 must be a digit zero through 8: " + Arrays.toString(idxZeroGridIdx_0to8));
     }

     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 0);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 1);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 2);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 3);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 4);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 5);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 6);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 7);
     printCellCoordinates(gridIdx, 8);
  }
  private static final void printCellCoordinates(int grid_idx, int cell_idx)  {
     int rowIdx = -1;
     if(grid_idx < 3)  {
        rowIdx = ((cell_idx < 3) ? 0
           :  ((cell_idx < 6) ? 1 : 2));
     }  else if(grid_idx < 6)  {
        rowIdx = ((cell_idx < 3) ? 3
           :  ((cell_idx < 6) ? 4 : 5));
     }  else  {
        rowIdx = ((cell_idx < 3) ? 6
           :  ((cell_idx < 6) ? 7 : 8));
     }
     int colIdx = (cell_idx % 3) + ((grid_idx % 3) * 3);

     System.out.println("grid=" + grid_idx + ", cell=" + cell_idx + " --> sudoku2DGridArray[" + rowIdx + ", " + colIdx + "]");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
rowIdx = 3*(grid_idx/3) + cell_idx/3
```

all division being integer divisions

Comment: Thank you. Works great. I'll be honest and say that @DavidWallace's answer is a tiny bit cleaner, but I'm going to support the underdog here  :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious to know how you find it "cleaner" ?

Comment: If I can offer a possible clue - I tossed up between this solution and the one that I posted, since both are good.  I decided that using `%` and `-` might be slightly more efficient than `/` and `*`, although I guess this depends on the processor architecture.  I may be wrong, but that's what swung it for me.  Note that you can avoid the parentheses if you write `grid_idx / 3 * 3 + cell_idx / 3` since `*` and `/` associate from left to right.

Comment: Cleaner is the wrong word. It's just closer to what I'd probably write myself, had I the mathematical experience/knowledge of you both. It seems like yours could *somehow* be reduced further, although I honestly couldn't say how. For example, why can't `(3 * (grid_idx / 3)` be reduced to just `grid_idx` (since 3*5/3 is, of course, 5). But I tried it and it doesn't work. This isn't a complaint, since your answer works flawlessly (and I bow down to your mad math skills), but it's just something that sticks out to me.

Comment: Well, `3 * 5 / 3` is not the same thing as `3 * (5 / 3)`.  One is 5, the other is 3.

Comment: Right. Of course. I'm going to just stop before I dig myself deeper  :)

Comment: I agree that @DavidWallace answer is probably a little faster (+1 by the way). But I won't call it cleaner either.

Comment: A tool?  This is about doing simple arithmetic operations with numbers between 0 and 9.  I can't imagine what sort of tool you'd use to help with this.

Comment: I agree with @DavidWallace. If you have trouble with that, you should refresh your memory with the notion of integer division, maybe compute a dozen by hand. With all due respect, it's very basic arithmetic.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'm posting the follow-up in a new question, to give you the change for more rep.

Answer (score 3):

That chunk with all the `?:` operators is just `grid_idx - grid_idx % 3 + cell_idx / 3`