# Given 2D array row/column index, how to formulate the Sudoku "sub-grid" index?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, sudoku

I'm working on implementing a Sudoku grid in Java, and the last thing I've been unable to do  is reduce the below logic to a mathematical formula.

*This is a follow up to this question: [How to get the Sudoku 2D-array index, given its "sub-grid" and "cell-in-the-sub-grid" indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22289144/2736496)*

Here is the function, which works well:

```
public static final int getGridIndexForCell(int rowIdx_0to8, int colIdx_0to8)  {
   int idx = -1;
   if(rowIdx_0to8 < 3)  {
      //Grid-row 1
      idx = ((colIdx_0to8 < 3) ? 0
          : ((colIdx_0to8 < 6) ? 1 : 2));

   }  else  if(rowIdx_0to8 < 6)  {
      //Grid-row 2
      idx = ((colIdx_0to8 < 3) ? 3
          : ((colIdx_0to8 < 6) ? 4 : 5));

   }  else  {
      //Grid-row 3
      idx = ((colIdx_0to8 < 3) ? 6
          : ((colIdx_0to8 < 6) ? 7 : 8));
   }
   return  idx;
}
```

It returns the "grid index", based on the provided row and column indexes of the underlying two-dimensional array.

Here's what I mean by grid (I call the entire thing a "board"):

```
        |         |
   0    |    1    |    2
        |         |
 -------------------------
        |         |
   3    |    4    |    5
        |         |
 -------------------------
        |         |
   6    |    7    |    8
        |         |
```

Where each grid has nine cells, indexed like this

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

I'd appreciate annotated answers, as much as that is possible, because this is something I'm just not getting yet.

Comment: something is messy here. How row can be 4 here? Or column = 4?

Comment: Sudoku is a 9x9 grid of *cells*, and a 3x3 grid of *sub-grids*. This code returns the sub-grid index, so there is no column 4 or row 4. (The term "grid" is confusing. I'm going to change it to "sub-grid").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the formula you want is

```
grid_index = (column / 3) + (row / 3) * 3 = column / 3 + row - row % 3
```

That is `grid_index` grows by one each time columns grow by `3` and `grid_index` grows by `3` each time `row` grows by `3`. Again all division done with integer.

Comment: Both versions work great, thank you. I am confused about the non-mod one though. Take a look at this spreadsheet: http://goo.gl/wi0HKE. There are two "sheets" in it, listed on the bottom. The "with mod" version has values as expected (the digit to the left of the decimal is the answer, which is what you mean by "all division done with integer"). Although it works perfectly in the Java code--I'm unit-testing every cell--in the non-mod spreadsheet and also in TTCalc (ttcalc.sourceforge.net) it's coming out wrong.

Comment: For example, with `row-idx=2` and `col-idx=3`: `(3/3) + (2/3) * 3` equals `3`, but it should be `1`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "all division done with integer". If you compute `(2/3)*3` with rational numbers then the `3` cancels and you get `2`. You gat get an approximation of that is C or Java using floats `(2./3.)*3. = 2.00000000000000`. Now if you compute with `int` `(int 2)/(int 3) = 0` and therefore `(2/3)*3 = 0`. It seems that TTCalc compute with float.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is

```
return (rowIdx_0to8  / 3)* 3 + (colIdx_0to8 / 3)
```

for rowIndex_0to8 = 7, colIdx_0to8 = 6
row 7 /3 = 2 * 3 = 6
column + 5 / 3 = 1
index = 7

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void f( int rowIdx_0to8, int colIdx_0to8) {
        System.out.println( 3 * Math.floor( rowIdx_0to8 / 3) +
                                                 Math.floor( colIdx_0to8 / 3));
}
```

or even simpler:

```
public static void f( int rowIdx_0to8, int colIdx_0to8) {
        System.out.println( 3 * ( rowIdx_0to8 / 3) + ( colIdx_0to8 / 3));
}
```

[online example](http://ideone.com/WhaNIK)

Comment: The function returns an int, so the `floor` version must be casted, but otherwise it works great. Thanks.